# Javascript - creating and acessing own set of data (array/object)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking for a good way to handle markers of googlemap.

What I need to do, is store markers in array (or object) and be able to adress them with a key (marker_1) and also be able to run through whole array and access all elements to deattach them from map.

Currently I have:

```
var markers = []; // global | was using var markers = {}; earlier

// and i add elemtnts like this ()

markers[elementid] = {
    lat: varlat,
    lng: varlng',
    desc: vardesc,
    markerobj: markerobject
}
```

Maybe I don't even know what I have anymore. Is it Array, is object or a hybrid (Never found any good resource to read about differences between those two).

I can, without problem access it with `markers["marker_1"]` syntax.
However, those do not allow me to loop throught object/array:

```
console.log(markers.length);
// returns 0. but array is defined while debugging code in firebug
for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
    console.log(markers[i]);
}
```

And

```
$(markers).each(function(a,b){
    alert('works');
});
```

simply does no work at all.

Why Can't I just create, walk and access  arrays like in PHP? :\

Comment: If elementid is a string (like you have "markers_1" as an example) then markers has to be an object, initialized as `= {}`, not an array.  Arrays are ONLY numerically indexed.  With an object, `.length` is not used, and to iterate the properties of an object use MasqueradeCircus' example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
for(var i in markers){
    console.log(markers[i]);
}
```

Maybe you're overwriting something. An array is based on indices, as you add a string as an index immediately becomes an object, and the only way to access your content is like the example that I put.

This would be another example that proves it:

```
var array = [];

array.push('1');
array['hola'] = {hola: 'mundo'};

for (i in array)
    console.log(array[i]);

console.log(array.length);
```

Comment: This also does not seem to wok. It's like its array, but completly without keys. It does not even start iteration.

Comment: Ok, this started to work, AFTER changing
var markers = []; to  var markers = {};

Answer (score 0):

You have to access then via markers['marker_'+(i+1)] in your for-loop because the elements are not accessible by index, but by their key.

Comment: Can I get nuber of elements at last somehow?

Comment: Only because it is defined does not mean is has conten, are you sure you "put something inside"?

Comment: Yes I am: http://gacekssj4.kei.pl/pidgin/2014-05-25_16-33-37.png However, i have doubts if its array or object.